# Show that $R$ is a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ a set with $+$ and $\cdot $ s.t.

1) $(R,+)$ is a group (not necessarily comutative)

2) $\cdot $ is associative, and distributive for $+$, i.e. $a\cdot (b\cdot c)=(a\cdot b)\cdot c$, $a\cdot (b+c)=a\cdot b+a\cdot c$ and $(a+b)\cdot c=a\cdot c+b\cdot c$

3) there is $1\in R$ s.t. $1\cdot x=x\cdot 1=x$.

Show that $R$ is a ring.

I really don't know how to did it. I think that I have to show that $(R,+)$ is commutative, but I didn't success.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:**

Compute
$$
(1 + 1) \cdot (a + b)
$$
in two ways, using the two distributive laws.

Comment: we get $a+a+b+b=(a+b)+(a+b)$ but I don't get the trick...

Comment: Now exploit the fact that $(G, +)$ is a group, so that you can simplify. In other words, add $-a$ ***on the left*** and $-b$ ***on the right***.

Comment: Very nice. thanks